# Why are my yarn scripts slow when calling other yarn scripts?

Tags: node.js, npm, vpn, yarnpkg

I am debugging why certain yarn scripts on my work laptop (mac running through a VPN) are running slowly, and have found that if I call another yarn script from the first, it takes around 8 and a half seconds consistently each time. This happens with any yarn script which calls another yarn script.

Example:

package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "date": "date",
  "date:foo": "yarn run date",
  "date:bar": "yarn run date:foo"
}
```

result:

```
$ yarn run date:bar
yarn run v1.22.4
$ date; yarn run date:foo
Tue Jul  7 15:52:28 EDT 2020
$ date; yarn run date
Tue Jul  7 15:52:37 EDT 2020
$ date
Tue Jul  7 15:52:45 EDT 2020
```

Scripts are perfectly fast when using npm run in scripts. The problem only manifests with yarn. On my personal laptop connected to home internet, these scripts are fast.

Is there a reason yarn might take extra time here when I'm connected to a VPN? What things is yarn doing in the background that might be slowing down these kinds of scripts?